# Why MySQL union all shows different result for "practically" the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I was making a query and I'm wrong with the results, I modified and it works, but the query is very similar as the original, look it:

ORIGINAL: (DIDN'T WORK)

```
select username, password from tbl_user
union all
select username as password, password as username from tbl_user
```

Results:

```
user1 | pass1
userUnion1 | passUnion1
```

SOLUTION: (WORKING)

```
select username, password from tbl_user
union all
select password as username , username as password from tbl_user
```

Results:

```
user1 | pass1
passUnion1 | userUnion1
```

The intension of the query is to union the same result but with the columns inverted, in the original query it doesn't invert the columns, but in the SOLUTION query it does it ¿why?

(Note in the ORIGINAL query I'm ordering to asume the password AS username and the username as password), Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first query:

```
select username, password from tbl_user
union all
select username as password, password as username from tbl_user
```

You are simply taking a union of `tbl_user` with itself.  The aliases in the second half of the union are ignored.  This query is identical to doing:

```
select username, password from tbl_user
union all
select username, password from tbl_user
```

Similarly, your working second query is identical to:

```
select username, password from tbl_user
union all
select password, username from tbl_user
```

The general rule of thumb for union queries in MySQL and most databases is that the types *and* number of columns are the same in each select list.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of the different result sets in a union are handled by their position (first, second, ...), not by column alias name.

Your first query would work if union operations worked by name.